# Is it possible in Python to have a function that creates many new variables with incrementally changing names

Tags: python, variables

I am trying to make a program that makes a new variable multiple times in a function:
my pseudo code:

```
increment = 1
"g" + increment = variable
increment = increment + 1
```

Comment: i was hoping to have a bunch of variables such as g1, g2, g3 and g4 with all inputed strings or integers

Answer (score 1):

You should use dictionaries:

```
dct = {}
increment = 1
while increment <= 10:
    dct[f'g{increment}'] = increment
    increment += 1
```

This will store the variables and values in a dictionary.

So you can print it like:

```
print(dct)
```

Or to get let's say the key `g3`, try:

```
print(dct['g3'])
```

You could also use `list`s to store the values, like this:

```
lst = []
increment = 1
while increment <= 10:
    lst += [[f'g{increment}', increment]]
    increment += 1
```

And then you could `print` the `lst`:

```
print(lst)
```

Comment: Excellent! Worth also calling out that `list`s are another way to store values (if the order matters more than the name).